# Laravel check if return of eloquent is single collection or collection of items

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I wants to know how to check if the return of Eloquent Query is single row from DB or multiple rows.

I tried `$record->count()` but it always return a value greater than 1 in the 2 cases.

**For example:**

```
$record = User::first();
return $record->count(); //it return the count of columns in users table
```

and if I tried to get all users;

```
$record = User::all();
return $record->count(); //it return the count of all rows in users table
```

So how to deal with this case ?

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `instanceof` construction to check what kind of data your variable is.

For your examples, this will likely be something like this:

```
$record = User::first();
$record instanceof \App\User; // returns true
$record instanceof \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection; // returns false

$record = User::all();
$record instanceof \App\User; // returns false
$record instanceof \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection; // returns true
```

Docs: https://secure.php.net/instanceof

Answer (score 2):

```
$record = ......;

if($record instanceof \Illuminate\Support\Collection){
  // its a collection
}
elseif($record instanceof \App\User){
  // its a single url instance
}
```

However, above will **not** work directly if you are using DB builders :

```
$record = DB::table('users')->get();
```

`$record` is an array. So you need to hydrate it so you can use above logic on it :

```
if(is_array($record){ 
   $record = \App\User::hydrate($record);
}
```

Now you can use if else logic on $record as its converted from an array to `\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection` which internally extends from `\Illuminate\Support\Collection`

Also, second case if someone did `first()` instead of `get()`:

```
$record = \DB::table('users')->first();
```

Then `$record` is an `stdClass` object. so you can avoid hydration and consider it as a single user data.

I am concerned about the system logic and patterns where you need to have this kind of conditional. If possible, I would recommend to refactor in such a way that you function always knows if it's a collection or an instance. You can use type hints in functions to be more clear.

Answer (score 1):

`first()` always returns only 1 row

```
$record = User::first(); // this will return only 1 records
```

To get number of rows in users table you need to create another query

```
$allrow = User::all();
return $allrow->count();
```

OR

```
$allrow = DB::table('users')->get();
return $allrow->count();
```

Answer (score 0):

`User::all()` returns an array of `User` So the simple way is to check if is an array.

```
if (is_array($record)){

}
```